# trying to kill a process of gathered pid using kill command

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "jakiś napis"
echo "jakiś napis"

A= ps -ef | grep calc | grep -v grep

echo $A

B= ps -ef | grep calc | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs

echo $B



kill -9 $B
```

In my bash script, I'm gathering the PID of the calc process which I would like to kill afterward.

The output of the script is:

```
jakiś napisjakiś napis
filip      38684    1856  0 00:58 ?        00:00:00 gnome-calculator

38684

kill: składnia: kill [-s sygnał | -n numer-sygnału | -sygnał] pid | zadanie ... lub 
kill -l [sygnał]
```

So the kill command throws an error. After running the script the calc process is still there. I do not understand how am I using the kill command in a wrong way?

Comment: Please include the error-message.

Comment: See [ProcessManagement - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), particularly the "How do I kill a process by name? ..." section.

Answer (score 0):

@Filip Machaj
Your usage of `xargs` is not correct,
either you pass argument to `xargs` something like `xargs sudo kill -9` or remove it.

I am pasting a slightly modified version of your shell script, you can pass the process name as 1st argument to the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

A=$(ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep)

echo $A
echo ""

B=$(ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')

echo "PID of $1 is $B"
sudo kill -9 $B
```

Or if you want to use `xargs` then,

```
#!/bin/bash

A=$(ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep)
B=$(ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
echo $A
echo ""
echo "PID of $1 is $B"
ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

then you can call your script assuming the name of script is `proc-kill.sh`,

`bash proc-kill.sh calc`